# Does Math.Sqrt cache its own results?

Tags: c#-4.0

Someone has suggested to me that the built in C# `Math.Sqrt` function in .NET 4.0 caches its results, so that if I call `Math.Sqrt(50)` over and over again, it's not actually doing a sqrt, but just pulling the answer from a cache. Can anyone verify or deny this claim? If it's true then I have a bunch of needless caching going on in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't have .net 4 installed but you can vrify this easily by viewing the said method in reflector.
this is the only way that you'll be sure to see what's going on.

Comment: I actually checked this out in both ildasm and .net reflector. It appears that there is no caching at the .NET level because both show that Math.Sqrt is actually an extern call.

Comment: You can't see this using reflector because it is an extern call. You could download the sources of the [shared source reference implementation](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8c09fd61-3f26-4555-ae17-3121b4f51d4d&displaylang=en) from Microsoft and have a look there. You would see that `Math.Sqrt` simply is a call to the `sqrt()` function in math.h of C++.

Answer (score 1):

I don't belive so.

You can try and do a benchmark, call `Math.Sqrt` on 1000.000 different numbers and then on 1000.000 same numbers, the time taken should be similar.

May you can have a look into reflector which reveals you (at least the unmanaged parts) of the `Math.Sqrt` function code.

If you need a cache, you should create one on your own with some kind of hashtable. 
Note that you should leave an epsilon, that is for example 1.0000000 should be considered the same as 1.00000001, otherwise you get into trouble with accuracy.